# How to update the db information from a form on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning ruby on rails and I have a little problem. I need to update my db when someone clicks on the update button but i dont knwo how to do it. this is the html.erb:

```
                      <%= form_with model: @user, url: edit_user_registration_url, method: :get do |f| %>
                        <div>
                        <input value="<%= @user.about %>">
                        </div>
                        <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
                      <% end %>
```

I need to update the @user.about information and show the same view with the about updated.

Comment: https://3rd-edition.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#mvc-and-you